# WSO2 esb access node from xml in property

Tags: wso2-esb

i stored an XML document in a property:

```
<property expression="$body//*" name="InDoc"
        scope="default" type="OM"/>
```

in a later step of the proxy a want to access the XML doucment.

This

```
 <log level="custom">
        <property name="InDoc" expression="get-property('InDoc')"/>
      </log>
```

gives the whole XML document. But I would like to access only some parts of the XML e.g. only one value in a later step of the proxy. I already tried

```
 <log level="custom">
        <property name="InDoc" expression="get-property('InDoc')//AAA"/>
      </log>
```

or this

```
<log level="custom">
        <property name="InDoc" expression="$ctx:InDoc//AAA"/>
      </log>
```

But both do not work. Is there another way?
Thanks in advance.

Roland

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think both way should work fine. The expression support XPath 1.0. You can run any XPath after the "get-property" in expression.

But you need check,

1. make sure you use the right XPath.
   So you can log/copy the get-property('InDoc'), and then you can use any [XPath tool](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath) to validate your XPath.
2. Namespace of the XPath in expression,
   if your xml payload have namespace, make sure your XPath namespace is right, and declare right NS in property.

Comment: In case without namespaces it seems not to work. But with namespaces we got it working now. Thanks!

Comment: It is very strange. it seems this feature ist not very reliable. I think we have to do some tests. Because now it does not work anymore.... :-(

Comment: @RolandMeuthen I use lots of xpath after the get-property, i think this should reliable. Please log/copy your xml of get-property, and use xpath tool validate your xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Through property mediator, you are not going to store XML file, you just retrieving content from it. As you have to retrieve part of it, you can give it through property mediator.

```
<property expression="$body//*" name="InDoc" scope="default" type="OM"/>
```

Through expression you should define it.

```
expression="$body//*"
```

You can change this and get required parts of xml. If you need few parts, you can add several properties for each and retrieve value from it.